# Can CREATE table have a UDT-type column in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, database

```
CREATE TYPE DBO.ADDRESSTYPE AS TABLE
(
    LocationName VARCHAR(50), 
    PIN NUMERIC
); 

CREATE TABLE mycustomer 
(
    cust_id NUMERIC, 
    name varchar(50), 
    current_address ADDRESSTYPE
);
```

Can someone help to create table with user defined dataype in sql server?

Comment: Though the duplicate question asks about two user defined table types the same rules apply to normal tables as well.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't support "nested" tables, so no, you cannot do this. Consider creating a separate (normal) `Addresses` table and then using foreign keys as appropriate between `Addresses` and `Customers`.